# one service for few notification actions

Tags: android, notifications

I created notification with actions. And for handling with notification i'm using service. For each action i created pending intent with some extra. But in the service, when i tried to get extra for intent i've got a wrong value of this. Here is my code:

class NotificationCreator

```
public Notification createConnectedNotification(){
    Context context = TeamlabApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence comeToWork = context.getString(R.string.toWork);
    CharSequence goFromDinner = context.getString(R.string.fromDinner);


    PendingIntent actionComeIntent = createActionSendPendingIntent(context, comeToWork.toString());
    Notification.Action.Builder sendMessageToWork =
            new Notification.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.icon_notification_action_send, comeToWork, actionComeIntent);

    PendingIntent actionDinnerIntent = createActionSendPendingIntent(context, goFromDinner.toString());
    Notification.Action.Builder sendMessageFromDinner =
            new Notification.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.icon_notification_action_send, goFromDinner, actionDinnerIntent);

    PendingIntent activityIntent = createActivityPendingIntent(context);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_notification_main)
            .setContentTitle("Connected to WI-FI")
            .setContentText("You connected to work WI-FI. Do you want to send message in teamLab")
            .setContentIntent(activityIntent)
            .setLights(Color.WHITE, 1000, 1000)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(sendMessageToWork.build())
            .addAction(sendMessageFromDinner.build());

    return builder.build();
}



private PendingIntent createActionSendPendingIntent(Context context, String extraMessage){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationService.MESSAGE_EXTRA, extraMessage);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

class NotficationService

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            AppLog.d("Extra is: " + intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_EXTRA));
        }
```

`String toWork = "To work" , goFromDinner = "From dinner"`. In notification i pressed acton with String `goFromDinner` but in Extra i have result `To work`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. You need to set different requestCode for different action. So now my code is:

```
private PendingIntent createActionSendPendingIntent(int requestCode, Context context, String extraMessage){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationService.MESSAGE_EXTRA, extraMessage);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```